# sharepoint error current simulation title not found

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i have installed sharepoint server envirement on my 2008 windows server.
i also configured a web application and created a site collection on http:/myserver/mysite
when i try to access these address i have this error which i cannot fix :(

*Error 
The resource object with key 'current_simulation_title' was not found. 
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: 907ae95c-b96e-462b-9d11-74646938990e 
Date and Time: 3/18/2013 12:40:10 PM*

PS: The sp central administration is located on http:/myserver:40000/

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of this error is that, Sharepoint cannot find the Resource key "current_simulation_title" , did u created any resource file and uploaded in sharepoint 14 hive?

Comment: No, i did not uploaded any file . What's mant by current simulation title ?